# sort details order by user id from another mysql table by activity less than 3600

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I wish to fetch all users from "members" table but also check if the member_id from members table and user_id exist in"login" table and then see if column "activity" (current_timestamp) is less than 3600 seconds in login table than order those users on top rest users if don't exist in login table shows those users in bottom?

how cani query this please.

this is how i fetch users

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id != '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";
```

but now how do i query the rest?

really thank you for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like

```sql
SELECT members.*
FROM members
JOIN logins ON members.member_id = logins.member_id
WHERE logins.logged_in_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3600 SECOND
-- AND members.member_id != '$_SESSION['tfs_member_id']'
```

JOIN provides the presence in `logins` table, WHERE by `logged_in_at` filters "active" logins.

Comment: almost working but then its not showing all users from members table. i wish all users to also show but display those users on top whose activity is less than 3600 seconds in login table

Comment: or i did order by instead of where and it worked yay :)

Comment: @Gracy Move the condition by activity from WHERE to ORDER BY clause - as binary (active/not active) or as numeric (use TIMESTAMPDIFF).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the `logins` table so you get members that aren't in the table. Then test whether the user is found in the `logins` table in the `ORDER BY` clause, and follow that by ordering by whether the last activity is recent.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN logins as l ON m.member_id = l.member_id
ORDER BY l.member_id IS NULL,
         l.activity > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) DESC
```